# Smooth transition of images in carousel in React

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have an image carousel that you can scroll through with a 'next' and 'prev' button. The buttons are setting the positions state. The positions state is passed to the styled component and serves as an array of "transform: rotateY" properties of the child elements. A snippet with relevant code can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-microservice-eylul?file=/src/App.js

My goal is to make the transitions of the images in the carousel smooth when the next and prev buttons are clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the transition to your CarouselCell styled component :

```
transition: all 1s;
```